# Hive: can't select a partition by two partition conditions

Tags: hadoop, hive

1. create external table wwwlogs (...) partitioned by (logdate string, nodeip string, tag string) ...
2. alter table wwwlogs add partition(logdate='2013-01-21', nodeip='192.168.1.101', tag='error');
3. alter table wwwlogs add partition(logdate='2013-01-20', nodeip='192.168.1.102', tag='access');
4. add other partitions.

The problem is:
1. show partitions wwwlogs partition (logdate='2013-01-21')  will list all partitions.
2. select count(1) from wwwlogs where logdate='2013-01-21' and tag='error':
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 1

Since number of mappers is 0, the select result is 0.

Comment: Are you sure there is some data under the partition that you are querying?
I don't see 'LOCATION' clause in your add partition statement.
Is there any data under HDFS folder ...wwwlogs/logdate=2013-01-21/nodeip=192.168.1.101/tag=error?

Comment: Sure. And "where logdate='2013-01-21' and tag='error'" get 0 result, but "where logdate='2013-01-21' and tag='error' and 1=1" will get correct result!

Comment: Plz give your query related mapreduce job's `mapred.input.dir` item value.